# Boxplot comparing female and male data alongside ALL data using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to compare the response (RRP) to different light treatments (Light) in female and male animals alongside the total combined data.
I used:

```r
emRRP <- melt(emper, id=c("Sex", "RRP", "Light"))
```

> data.frame(emRRP)
> Sex        RRP Light
> 1     F 0.63916773  AA30
> 2     F 0.71016609  AA30
> 3     F 0.40279640  AA30
> 4     F 0.69812010  AA30
> 17    M 0.76417910  AA30
> 18    M 0.71837927  AA30
> 19    M 0.95454545  AA30
> 20    M 0.69392225  AA30

I can plot the female and male data:

```
emRRPLT <- factor(
    emRRP$Light, 
    levels = c("LD", "LA05", "LA30", "LA50", "LA80", "AA30", "LL", "DD")
)

ggplot(emRRP, aes(x=emRRPLT, y=RRP, color=Sex)) +
   geom_boxplot() + 
   theme_classic() + 
   labs(x="Light treatment")
```

[Boxplot of female vs male responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh06X.png)

but don't know how to add the combined data alongside it.

Comment: Please provide real data (e.g., `data.frame(.)` or output from `dput(.)`), not a picture of it (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you provided an subset of the actual data rather than a picture so we could test solution. Anyway, you should be able to do what you want by just appending the dataset to itself and creating a new grouping variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mutate(emRRPLT, group=SEX) %>%
   bind_rows(mutate(emRRPLOT, group="All")) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=emRRPLT, y=RRP, color=group)) +
   geom_boxplot() + 
   theme_classic() + 
   labs(x="Light treatment")
```

Comment: That brings back "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1290): x"

Comment: I don't know how to add actual data without it being a big jumble of numbers.

Comment: As I said, it's difficult to debug without the actual data. See suggestion by r2evans above, probably the best thing is to post the output of `dput`: it may be a jumble of numbers but we can copy and paste into R! Just subset only a subset of a few lines, e.g. `small <- emRRPLT[1:20, ]`